# Where to go with mixed voice training?

Tags: voice

I've learned to transition from chest voice to head voice without a break. However, the quality of my higher registers is not satisfying yet. The figure below shows the spectrogram between 2 and 10 kHz of sweeps from approximately C#3 to C#5.

(a) is how it looks when I'm trying to maximize the resonance. I like the natural timbre of my chest voice, but you can see that there is a pretty dramatic change in the timbre going on, as I ascend in pitch. Most notably, the 5th formant and the 1st antiformant switch places. As a result, the character of my voice changes in a way I don't like. The uniqueless of my voice is lost, it sounds thin or overly compressed and like a completely different person. Obviously the changes are due to a significant rise of my larynx.

So I tried to keep the larynx in the same position, as I ascend, which results in something like the spectrum shown in (b). Indeed, the formants stay at their places and the timbre of my voice does not change a lot. However, as I go up, the resonance is lost more and more. Consequently the tone sounds weak and dull. Even though the larynx is in its neutral position of the chest voice, in the mixed/head voice it sounds and also feels like a lowered larynx in chest voice would.

[image: Spectrogram between 2 and 10 kHz of sweeps from approximately C#3 to C#5. (a) Maintaining the resonance, (b) constant larynx position.]

So I'm wondering, which way to go with my practice. Is it possible to retain the timbre of the chest voice while also developing a powerful resonance? Will the practice of keeping the larynx lower take care of that? Or should I relinguish developing a consistent, balanced tone across the registers and the best thing I can do is letting the larynx do its thing and follow the resonance, as I've done when building my chest voice?

Comment: A clarification: Are you asking how to make your mixed voice sound identical to your chest voice, just higher in pitch?

Comment: I do not know the answer.  I've had very little vocal training.  But in that tiny bit of vocal training, i got the impression the most important thing is to master breath support, and everything comes from that.

Comment: @Aaron more or less. I'm asking if it's possible to make my mixed voice share the characteristics that make my chest voice memorable. It seems to boil down to the question if it's necessary to have the larynx go up with pitch or if it's possible to develop a powerful and relaxed tone also without letting the larynx ascend.

Comment: @Aron It's clear that with the lower vibrating mass of the vocal folds, the mixed voice will sound lighter though.